# Nokogiri removing xml encoding

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using nokogiri to decode some xml.  This xml does have some html as values.  I am seeing some strange behavior when parsing this.  It appears nokogiri is removing some of the html encoded tags, so when i parse the html I am unable to decode it properly.  See examples below:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML '<?xml version="1.0"?><manifest 
xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" 
identifier="Manifest-eaf97d26-aa83-4399-8e9b-ae9f6f5fc6a2" 
xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" 
xmlns:imsmd="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_v1p2" 
xmlns:imsqti="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1">
<imsmd:langstring>&lt;p&gt;&#xd; These are the&lt;strong&gt;instructions&lt;/strong&gt; for the pool&lt;/p&gt;</imsmd:langstring>'
```

this yields the following value:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<manifest xmlns=\"http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1\" xmlns:imsmd=\"http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_v1p2\" xmlns:imsqti=\"http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1\" identifier=\"Manifest-eaf97d26-aa83-4399-8e9b-ae9f6f5fc6a2\">\n<imsmd:langstring>p&#xD; These are thestrong instructions/strong for the pool/p</imsmd:langstring></manifest>\n"
```

Notice how the < > tags are missing.  However the following works as expected.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML '<?xml version="1.0"?><imsmd:langstring>&lt;p&gt;&#xd; These are the&lt;strong&gt; instructions&lt;/strong&gt; for the pool&lt;/p&gt;</imsmd:langstring>'
```

and gives the following result

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<imsmd:langstring>&lt;p&gt;&#xD; These are the&lt;strong&gt; instructions&lt;/strong&gt; for the pool&lt;/p&gt;</imsmd:langstring>\n"
```

I am sure I am missing something but can't figure out what is causing this.